# Java: How to define a collection of Enums that implements an interface

Tags: generics, java-8

I want to create a class with two simple methods - the first registers a type that needs to be processed. The second will process all the types that have been registered. The problem I've got is that the classes I want to register/process have certain limits - they must be Enums that implement and interface

I can't quite work out how to define the collection that will be used to store the registered types. A simplified version of my code is:

```
public class Example {
    interface MyType {
        // Add methods here
    }

    private List<what-goes-here?> store = new ArrayList<>();


    public <T extends Enum<?> & MyType> void registerType(@Nonnull Class<T> type) {
        store.add(type);
    }


    public void processAll() {
        for (T t : store) {         // Where do I define T?
            // process t
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is inconsistent. In `register`, you are storing `Class` objects into the list, in `processAll`, you are expecting `T` instances to come out of it. Besides that, why is it important that these objects are `enum`s? There doesn’t seem to be any dependency on that property and it’s hard to imagine, how it could become a useful property.

Comment: @Holger Hi, I think he want to process all enum constant instances.

Comment: @holi-java A questioner should not require us to guess about their intentions. There are likely a lot of better solutions, depending on what they *actually* want to do.

Comment: @Holger yeah, you are right. but I have already give the answer...

Comment: @Eugene: in general… sometimes you simply want to mandate that a type fulfills two contracts, without the need to extends another type extending both. E.g. I could mandate that the type of the elements I’m processing implements both, `CharSequence` and `Comparable`. There are imaginable use cases and already matching existing classes, `String` and `CharBuffer`, that such generic code would support out-of-the-box. But there is no `ComparableCharSequence` that could be used instead of the intersection type.

Comment: @Holger thank you... it's probably just my personal shortcoming of not working enough with generics. thx again

Comment: @Holger I complete agree with you. describe it perfectly.

Comment: @Holger - thanks for your input. I was trying to keep the question as simple and concise as possible so i didn't go into the details of WHY I need the base class to be an enum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
public class Example {

    interface MyType {
        // Add methods here
    }

    //                  v--- save it as enum class
    private List<Class<? extends Enum<?>>> store = new ArrayList<>();


    public <T extends Enum<?> & MyType> void registerType(@Nonnull Class<T> type) {
        store.add(type);
    }


    public void processAll() {
        //           v--- iterate each enum type
        for (Class<? extends Enum<?>> type : store) {
            Enum<?>[] constants = type.getEnumConstants();
            for (Enum<?> constant : constants) {
                //v--- downcasting to the special interface
                MyType current = (MyType) constant;
                // TODO
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: in this case just declare store to hold `Object`, it does not really matter since you are casting any way as far as I can tell

Comment: @Eugene hi, thanks for your feedback. but if you save a `Class` as an `Object` it will generate unchecked warnings in `processAll`, this is why I  save it as an `Enum<?>` rather than `MyType`. Am I right, my dear? :)

Comment: I know, but you can obviously suppress that... you are not exposing `store` anyway (it's private). If you would expose it, then `MyType current = (MyType) constant` could theoretically still fail, since some enum instance would not implement `MyType`.

Comment: yeah, but I need downcasting twice, one for the `Class<Enum<?>`, another for the `MyType`. :)

Comment: yes, but that would still be safe, the only place where `store` is populated is via `registerType` and the compiler will ban everything that you need it to; well I guess that's just me being weird... never mind... still plus one

Comment: @Eegene yes, we are right. but Holger put the problem source in the comment, it is a very nice explaination. thanks for your up-vote, my dear.